# ansible add host to multiple groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am not sure if below can be achieved via ansible.
I have got list of hosts as belows: NOTE: Host can be repeated across groups

> Region: US 
>  Stage: QA 
>  Host: Host1 
>  Region: US 
>  Stage: UAT 
>  Host: Host2 
>  
>   Region: London 
>  Stage: QA 
>  Host: Host3 
>  Region: London 
>  Stage: UAT 
>  Host:
>   Host1

Now I may want to run certain tasks on all the Hosts in US group. Or I may want to run Host with region us and stage as qa. Or I may want to run all the host belonging to QA group. So how can i achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Because this is covered in the docs early on and is pretty straight forward. Also your example doesn't actually have a host in multiple groups.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: Apologies for the miss, but host can repeat itself across groups as a sample Host1 can be in 2 regions but different stage as shown in the updated example. For now I have a temporary fix with groups as "region_stage" and host. So I have multiple permutation and combinations of groups

Answer (score 1):

Define the inventory file as:

```
[US]
Host1
Host2

[London]
Host1
Host3

[QA]
Host1
Host3

[UAT]
Host1
Host2
```

> run certain tasks on all the Hosts in US group.

```
hosts: US
```

> run Host with region us and stage as qa

```
hosts: US:&QA
```

> run all the host belonging to QA group

```
hosts: QA
```

For one more pattern (exclusion) which you did not ask for explicitly, refer to the documentation on [patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html).

Comment: But I will have to list hosts multiple times across groups?..is there option of subgroups under a group? I was not able to locate it in ansible docs

Comment: ok..so forget about subgroups..but can you suggest any way where i might not need to mention hosts multiple times and not create multiple groups with different permutation and combination of REGION and STAGE values?

Comment: However I don't understand your understanding of question-and-answer idea that StackExchange implements.

Comment: The solution what u've suggested i've already implemented as temporary fix (as mentioned in my comment above). Won't Your solution run tasks twice on a certain host if I use hosts: "US:&QA"? So if you have a better solution to avoid duplication of hosts as well as to avoid creating multiple P & C of groups then please suggest